# Keep getting error when using += operation between two variables - Python

Tags: python

I currently have a bit of code that adds a certain amount of points to a plyers score:

```
points = 5
player1 = 0
float(points)
float(player1)
player1 += points
points = 0
```

The problem is when I run this I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'
```

At first, I thought it had to do with the data types of the variables, points and player1 but I have a float function right before it. Also just for debugging purposes I wrote a `bool` statement `print(bool(float(var)))` to check if it was floating correct and it wasn't. The points variable floated correctly but it was saying that `player1` was not a `float`. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: `float(points)` doesn't change `points`. It should be `points = float(points)`

Comment: That error can't happen with the code you showed. `points = 5` makes it an `int`, not `str`.

Comment: This code doesn't have any string variables.  Show us the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reading user input, you need to assign the result of `float` to the variable.

```py
points = float(points) # convert existing string, or use float(input())
player1 = float(player1)
```

Comment: Ok I'm stupid can't believe I forgot this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I was not able to reproduce the error, meaning I executed your code and did not get the error.

[image: All good (using Programiz)]

Second: When you cast a variable as: float(points) you must save the casting in a variable (or update the previous one).

```
points = float(points)
```

Note: in your case, you don't need to cast the variable to float because you are using only int values.